# Beautiful Soup is giving none, though value is present

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Why my following code is giving an output `NONE`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
urllib3.disable_warnings()
url = "https://www.amazon.ae/dp/B07N62ZGWQ/ref=br_msw_pdt-5?_encoding=UTF8&smid=ABO0A2K2SKD5O&pf_rd_m=A2KKU8J8O8784X&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=GZ376KPZWEXC0TBHXPKY&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=da8f558b-6ee9-4705-8e31-6a4c345b29e8&pf_rd_i=desktop"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', url)
content = r.data.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', {'id':"priceblock_ourprice"}))
```

I tried using `soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")`, `soup.select("#priceblock_ourprice")`, but both gave None output .

ID is present on the page and has a value as well.

[image]

Comment: You are checking different things: the content variable and what you see when you open the URL in your brower. Try print (content) and open the html in your browser to see the page you are actually getting

Comment: print the soup to check that what you expect is really there and not populated with a javascript

Comment: I have checked the content and the element is present there as well.

Comment: amazon uses JavaScript to add elements and requests/beautifulsoup can't run JavaScript. Open web browser, turn off JavaScript and load amazon page to see what beautifulsoup can see. You may have to use Selenium to control web browser which will load page, run JavaScript and then you can get HTML from Selenium.

Comment: you can also have other situation: amazon may recognize that you run script and it may send page with warning for bots or with captch. You may write `content` to file and open in browser to see what you get.

Comment: I tested code - if I use `html.parser` and `find` then it can't find it. If I use `lxml` and `find` then it finds it.

Comment: yes that worked, can you tell me why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I altered `urllib3` to `requests` because `urllib3` was giving an exception

See the code below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.ae/dp/B07N62ZGWQ/ref=br_msw_pdt-5?_encoding=UTF8&smid=ABO0A2K2SKD5O&pf_rd_m=A2KKU8J8O8784X&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=GZ376KPZWEXC0TBHXPKY&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=da8f558b-6ee9-4705-8e31-6a4c345b29e8&pf_rd_i=desktop"

response = requests.request('GET', url)
content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'a-lineitem'})
price_blocks = table.find_all('span', attrs={'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'})
prices = [block.text for block in price_blocks]
print(prices)
```

Output console:

```
['AED26.00']
```